# Executing a function that accesses global array on multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have a function 'graph1' that calls another function as shown below. When I call

```
graph1threader(copy, date);
```

I get the answer I want, however this takes upwards of 30 seconds, so I tried using multithreading. However when I use

```
thread[copy] = new Thread(() => graph1threader(copy, date));//pass date,copy
thread[copy].Start();
```

I get no result i.e. the global variables hold only 0. Why is this? And how may I rectify this?

```
void graph1()
    {

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {                
            int copy = k;
            DateTime date = G.AddDays(copy);
            refValues[copy] = 0;
            threshValues[copy] = 0;
            y_Values[copy] = 0;
            y__Values[copy] = 0;
            yValues[copy] = 0;

            //task[copy] = new Task(() => graph1threader(copy, date));//pass date,copy
            //ask[copy].Start();
            graph1threader(copy, date);

        }



            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                DateTime temp = G.AddDays(j);
                string temper = temp.ToShortDateString();
                y__Values[j] = y__Values[j] - y_Values[j];
                xNames[j] = temper;
            }

        chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, y_Values);

        chart1.Series[2].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, y__Values);

        chart1.Series[3].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, refValues);

        chart1.Series[4].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, threshValues);

        chart1.Series[5].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);

    }

void graph1threader(int x, DateTime date)
    {
        DBConnect A = new DBConnect();
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[4];
        list = A.mandetselect();
        int numberofmen = A.Countmandet();
        string[] man_name = list[0].ToArray();
        string[] trade = list[1].ToArray();
        string[] license = list[2].ToArray();
        string[] training = list[3].ToArray();
        string[] display_status = list[4].ToArray();
        //string abc;
        List<string>[] lista = new List<string>[5];
        List<string>[] listc = new List<string>[14];


        for (int j = 0; j < numberofmen; j++)
        {
            int flag = 0;
            if (!display_status[j].Equals("NO") && (selection == "ALL" || (selection == "LAE" && license[j] != "") || (selection == "NON LAE" && license[j] == "") || (selection == "ALL AVIONICS" && trade[j] == "Avionics") || (selection == "NON LAE AVIONICS" && trade[j] == "Avionics" && license[j] == "") || (selection == "LAE AVIONICS" && trade[j] == "Avionics" && license[j] != "") || (selection == "ALL AIRFRAMES" && trade[j] == "Airframes") || (selection == "NON LAE AIRFRAMES" && trade[j] == "Airframes" && license[j] == "") || (selection == "LAE AIRFRAMES" && trade[j] == "Airframes" && license[j] != "")))
            {
                refValues[x]++;
                threshValues[x] = 0.8 * refValues[x];
                string abc = man_name[j].Replace(" ", "_");
                int no_of_proj = A.Countproj(abc);//required
                lista = A.manprojselect(abc);//required
                string[] projname = lista[0].ToArray();
                string[] country = lista[2].ToArray();
                string[] startofproj = lista[3].ToArray();
                string[] endofproj = lista[4].ToArray();
                string Status = "";
                listc = A.Select();
                int numberc = A.Count();//number of projects, not required
                string[] nameofproj = listc[0].ToArray();
                string[] status = listc[13].ToArray();

                for (int l = 0; l < A.Countproj(abc); l++)
                {

                    for (int m = 0; m < numberc; m++)
                    {
                        if (nameofproj[m] == projname[l])
                        {
                            Status = status[m];
                        }
                    }


                    DateTime shuru = DateTime.ParseExact(startofproj[l],
                                   "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    DateTime anth = DateTime.ParseExact(endofproj[l],
                                   "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    if (date >= shuru && date <= anth)
                    {


                        if (Status != "PLANNED" && Status != "LO" && flag == 0)
                        {
                            y_Values[x]++;//BASIC UTILISATION
                            flag = 1;
                        }
                        if (Status == "IP" || Status == "OTD")
                            y__Values[x]++;//EXCESS
                        if (Status == "PLANNED")
                        {
                            yValues[x]++;//UNUTILISED

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I came across multi-threading only recently. So excuse me if the code doesn't look very good.
`threshValue[]`,`refValues[]`,`y_Values[]`, `y__Values[]`, `yValues[]` are all global variables

Comment: No, I have tried running the code again. It works fine, but the incremented values are not reflected in the global variable. However, when I used thread.join(), I got the result I wanted, but with a time delay of about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multithreading does not automagically make your program run faster, and `Thread.Join` simply waits for the thread to complete.

Basically if your main thread cannot continue until the thread has completed, you should not use multithreading.

Examples of where multithreading does fit:

- when trying to download information from several locations, you can let multiple threads wait for data from one location each
- when you want to perform a time-consuming task while keeping the user interface responsive

The second example may be the case here, but `Thread.Join` is a blocking operation: it still stops the user interface from being updated while the thread is working. In that case, you'd have to let the thread inform the main thread of its completion.

I don't know on what platform you're working here, but for instance on windows forms, the `Form` class has an `Invoke` method which lets you call a method on that form's thread:

```
class TheForm
{
    // the method running in a separate thread
    void myThread()
    {
        // do the time consuming work
        byte[] myData = ProcessData();

        // send data to the main thread 
        Invoke(new Action<byte[]>(ThreadCompleted), myData);
    }

    // will be executed in the main thread
    void ThreadCompleted(byte[] data)
    {
        // process the data
    }
}
```

About global variables and multithreading: any thread can access them, but there's no telling *which* thread accesses them *when*. If you can, you should avoid letting multiple threads access them, or use a `lock` mechanism to protect them.

Answer (score 0):

After much study and experimentation. I'vs learnt that the problem was not due to lack of multithreading, but rather connecting too often to the database (within my loops.)

My solution was to get all the data in bulk from the database before going into my loops. This saved a lot of precious time.